# Can organisations like Extinction Rebellion be sued for costs incurred as a result of them protesting?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales

If an organisation like ER or specific others are planning to disrupt the airport's operation (re https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-49509852) and that incurs me financial costs as I may need to re-book flights or bear related fees, is there any way I could sue them for any of this?

Comment: Related (possible dupe): [What power do I have if my interstate jouirney is blocked by a protest?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/15190/4595).

Comment: @TimLymington possibly, though that's USA, it may be different from UK/England. Thanks nonetheless :)

Comment: It's more likely that the airport/airlines affected would be the ones to sue them and then refund customers. Or possibly insurance companies to recoup the cost of travel insurance claims related to the protests. But it does happen, EDF sued some protesters for expenses incurred (they subsequently dropped the case because of negative publicity). 
https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-nottinghamshire-21537939